# Question: in R, wireframe error; empty box with nothing in it

Tags: r

i want to make some 3d plot in R and used the wireframe command but i cannot see the datas, i only cansee an empty box with nothing in it.

```
library(lattice)
x <- c(38.02, 49.56, 132.98, 55.65, 129.44, 83.04 ,103.52, 99.59, 100.13)
y <- c(2.35 ,2.39 ,5.41 ,0.55 ,3.12 ,0.41 ,0.31 ,0.47 ,0.37 )
z <- c(-63, -42, -27, -21, -18, -9, -4.5, -3, -1.5)
wireframe(y ~ z*x, drape=TRUE, 
          xlab = "loss",
          ylab = "tree",
          zlab = "mass")
```

How can i plot this?

Comment: Function `wireframe` is not a base R function. Please start your script with a call to `library(pkgname)` to load the package where `wireframe` can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the lattice package, this may work.

```
library(lattice)
x <- c(38.02, 49.56, 132.98, 55.65, 129.44, 83.04, 103.52, 99.59, 100.13)
y <- c(2.35, 2.39, 5.41, 0.55, 3.12, 0.41, 0.31, 0.47, 0.37)
z <- c(-63, -42, -27, -21, -18, -9, -4.5, -3, -1.5)
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(x, y, z))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "z")
wireframe(y ~ z * x, drape = TRUE,data = df,
      xlab = "loss",
      ylab = "tree",
      zlab = "mass")
```

Comment: Thanks, now i understand the problem of my codes! thanks :)

Comment: @Kang_HM that's great, would you mind accepting the answer?